# Why does SFTP return "permission denied" even when user has highest privileges?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp

**that seemed to work-> sftp .. garyfiles@127.0.0.1 (on the same muchine)**
I want to implement an FTP over two Linux(Ubuntu 20.04) munchies in order to allow a user to upload files into my server without giving him/her permissions to do anything else on the server side.

*will specify constraints the end alongside fixes I already tried *

The method I chose to do it is by creating a new user on the server side and restrict its access to one directory.

So on server side:

```
sudo adduser garyfiles  
mkdir -p /var/sftp/uploads  
chown root:root /var/sftp  
chmod 755 /var/sftp
chown garyfiles:garyfiles /var/sftp/uploads
```

and edited and appended the sshd_config file to Match user with ->

```
Match User garyfiles
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

at this point I restarted sshd -> `systemctl restart sshd`
and on client side`sftp user@{user_IP}`

When trying to execute `sftp user@{user_IP}` I am prompted to user password, once supplied I get "Permission denied, please try again."

Already tried and didn't help:

1. change ownership of ~/upload to root for max permissions
2. creating a new users group and assigning it garyfiles and root users
3. creating a new group for original, garyfiles and root users.
4. change privileges of upload to allow  full access to every one: `chmod 664 /var/sftp/upload`
5. sftp -v did not return  valuable  clues..

Constraints to consider and assumptions I can make:

1. SFTP would utilize password authentication (and not SSH)
2. user must not have access to other folders on the machine
3. Both devices would be connected to the same LAN

Comment: Check the syslogs on the server to see if sshd (the ssh server process) is logging the reason why it's rejecting the user.

Comment: Thanks! 
This is what I am getting, foes it make any sense to you?  
May  2 18:11:48 ofir systemd[1]: Started snap.code.code.59457900-bb9f-4eb1-b7ef-ef286c5e8ae7.scope.
May  2 18:11:49 ofir systemd[1]: snap.code.code.59457900-bb9f-4eb1-b7ef-ef286c5e8ae7.scope: Succeeded.
May  2 18:12:09 ofir systemd[1]: Started snap.code.code.0a681491-ccae-4f0e-8ad2-c828a4e98870.scope.
May  2 18:12:09 ofir systemd[1]: snap.code.code.0a681491-ccae-4f0e-8ad2-c828a4e98870.scope: Succeeded.

Comment: None of those log entries appear to have come from sshd.

Comment: @OfirOzery you are looking in the wrong log file, look at the most recent entries in the SSH authentication log at /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Hi tried to read auth.log and there are no indicators/clues to why its closing, just opened.. closed.. thing is that when I added sudo to the sftp it worked on my end(did not get permmision denied) but now I get permmision denied onthe server side..